# How to display images from a JSON URL array in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, json, react-hooks

I have converted a JSON endpoint into a JavaScript array and I've mapped through it to get the key values I need. 3 out of 4 are text values but the first one is an image and it just displays the URL link. I have tried to map through the same array and display just the images and it works but then I cannot merge the two elements into one div.

The code:

```
export default function Pokes() {

  const [pokemonData, setPokemonData] = React.useState({});

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch(
      "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Biuni/PokemonGO-Pokedex/master/pokedex.json"
    )
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => setPokemonData(data.pokemon));
  }, []);

  const allPokes = pokemonData;
  const pokemons = Object.values(allPokes);
  
  const pokesData = pokemons.map(pokemon => `${pokemon.img} ${pokemon.num} ${pokemon.name} ${pokemon.type}`);

let renderedOutput = pokesData.map(item => <div className="infodiv" style={{ flex: 1, flexBasis: "33%" }}> {item} </div>)


 return (
        <main>
          <div>
         
            <div style={{ display: "flex", flexWrap: "wrap" }}>{renderedOutput}</div>
           
          </div>
        </main>
      );

}
```

Comment: You need am `<img>` element and set the `src` with the url

Answer (score 2):

```
const pokesData = pokemons.map(pokemon => `${pokemon.img} ${pokemon.num} ${pokemon.name} ${pokemon.type}`)
```

This line of code would return "image url number name", what you actually want is the real image which requires the use of the `img` HTML tag. Implementing this with your code, it would become:

```
export default function Pokes() {

  const [pokemonData, setPokemonData] = React.useState({});

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch(
      "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Biuni/PokemonGO-Pokedex/master/pokedex.json"
    )
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => setPokemonData(data.pokemon));
  }, []);

  const allPokes = pokemonData;
  const pokemons = Object.values(allPokes);

  let renderedOutput = pokemons.map(pokemon => <div className="infodiv" style={{ flex: 1, flexBasis: "33%" }}>  <img src={pokemon.img} /> {pokemon.num} {pokemon.name}  </div>)
// Note the code change above ^^^

 return (
        <main>
          <div>
         
            <div style={{ display: "flex", flexWrap: "wrap" }}>{renderedOutput}</div>
           
          </div>
        </main>
      );

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution if that is what you are looking after. Here is [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-images-from-json-2g0pi?file=/src/App.js:0-751) for below code;

```js
import { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const URI =
  "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Biuni/PokemonGO-Pokedex/master/pokedex.json";

const App = () => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState([]);

  const getPokomonGo = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.get(URI);
      if (data) setValues(data?.pokemon);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log({ err });
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    getPokomonGo();
  }, [getPokomonGo]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Pokemon Images</h1>
      {values &&
        values.map(({ num, name, img }) => (
          <img src={img} alt={name} key={num} />
        ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: The above solution worked but I'll try this one as well. Thanks.

Comment: @KamilTkacz i am happy it helped you. can you please upvote the solution as well.

Comment: Like I siad up there I'd like to but I don't have the reputation 15 yet or is there another way I could do it? Best

Answer (score 0):

```html
<img src={{item.img}} alt="Lamp" width="100" height="100">
```